# Subdivision surface modifier displays strange results

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to model the 2nd generation Apple Pencil which has a flat section along the top. I was able to model a low poly version of the device, but when i added the subdivision surface modifier, it didn't quite provide the results i was looking for. I added an edge crease along the outer edge of the flat section, but it only made it worse. Is there an issue with the mesh itself, or is it just the subdivision surface modifier?

Here is a google drive link that contains the blend file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13cy7EwEumLTFE1v7ZwMdPU0pa_94bfev/view?usp=sharing

[image: This is the wireframe of the low poly model with the faces i'm concerned with selected]

[image: This is the low poly model.]

[image: This is the model with the subdivision surface modifier.]

[image: This is the model with subdivision surface modifier and an edge crease along the outer edge of the flat section.]

[image: This is what i'm trying to achieve.]

Comment: Can you show the wireframe view of your mesh and indicate exactly which faces you are not satisfied with and why?

Comment: @Carlo I have attached a screenshot of the wireframe with the faces i'm concerned with selected. Without the subdivision surface modifier, they look just fine; however, with the modifier, the surrounding edges do not maintain the correct curvature as seen in the 5th image. I have also attached a google drive link containing the blend file if that makes it any easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add a face inset once more to get the flat top. See this image.[image][image: Answer image]

Comment: I added the face inset to the flat faces and it definitely improved the flat top. However, my main concern is the curvature of the ends of the flat top. I think I may be able to fix it by adding an edge loop along the middle of the object and then sliding it closer to the ends.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I realized all I had to do was add an edge loop in the center of the object and slide it closer to the end of the flat section of the object. This along with adding a face inset (thank you @Parzeval for the suggestion), helped achieve the correct curvature.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I saw your blender file and found out the easiest way to solve this problem was to increase the mean crease of the following edges:
[image]

and now the pencil looks like this:

[image]

**A crease is needed along the edge or edges to sharpen up some of this object.**
**solved**